# How can I reRender Child Component from Main Component when state changes in RN 0.61?

Tags: react-native

I have two components Main and Child

```
export default class Main extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Child item={this.state.selectedItem} />
      </View>
    )
  }

}


export default class Child extends Component {

  state = {
    newItem: null
  };

  organiseProductOptions() {
    const { item } = this.props;
    Async Request with item.ID... {
      setState({ newItem: response })
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.organiseProductOptions();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{this.state.newItem.name}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }

}
```

Normally, this.organiseProductOptions() function is working in componentDidMount() initial state. However, When I try to rerender Child, render() method is working but componentDidMount() is not working.

How can I fire, this.organiseProductOptions() function in Child Component, when I setState selectedItem property at another time in Main Component?

**Please note that, Child Component has own states.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `Child` mounts only once you can check when `Child`'s props are changed and do your requests. Add

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (prevProps.item !== this.props.item) { // 'item' is changed
    this.organiseProductOptions();
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much... you save my day... 
Happy new year

Answer (score 0):

The child component **re-renders** when the props change but it doesn't **remount**. So when the child mounts it will set newItem as this.props.item, but after that newItem will never change.

The standard practice would be to just use this.props.item everywhere in your child component.

Comment: Hi James thank you for your answer, but as told before the child component has own states. So I have to make async api call then I have to write response of that.

Comment: It seems unlikely that your child component needs to have its own state for essentially the same thing... You'll end up with no single source of truth. It would be better to handle your API call in the parent and pass it down.